# jquery trying up update modal dialog with data retrieved via ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, modal-dialog

I have a page on which the users contact information is displayed.  If they need to change it, there's an "Edit" button which opens a modal dialog box containing the form with the field values set to the current data.  That works fine.

Within the form is a "country" field, which when changed triggers an ajax call that gets html for either a select box with the states of the new country selected or displays an text input to enter the state.

I had an earlier version (different size, jquery 1.7) that it worked on ... the code for that was:

```
$('#edit-contact-link').click(function(){
    $('#dialog-contact-form-edit').dialog("open");
    return false;
});

$('#dialog-contact-form-edit').dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    width: 450,
    height: 600,
    open: function () {
       $("#Country").change(function() {
            var country = $(this).val();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "includes/ajax/countrystate.php",
                data: {
                    Country: country
                },
                dataType: "html",
                success: function(data) {
                    //alert(data);
                    $('#state-dropdown').empty().html(data); // fill the state with the right data
                }
            }); // end .ajax
        }); // country change function
    },
    buttons: {
        Submit: function() {
            $("form[name='contactform']").submit();
            $(this).dialog('close');
        },
        Cancel: function() {
            $(this).dialog('close');
        }
    }
});
```

I tried using the same code on the new site (modifying the selectors and ajax file names slightly) and it didn't work at all.

I finally got everything to work (except filling in the #state-dropdown div with the ajax data) by calling the dialog directly with the click of the edit button and creating a separate function using the on() method for triggering the ajax call on change of the #Country select field.

Partially successful code:

```
$(document).on("change", "[id='Country']", function() {
    var country = $(this).val();
    var state = "";
    //alert("Country "+ country + " AND State " + state);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "includes/functions/form-func/ajax-countries-states.php",
        data: {
            Country: country,
            State: ""
        },
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
            $('#state-dropdown').empty().html(data); // fill the state with the right    data
        }
    }); // end .ajax 
}); // country change function

$('.contact-edit').click(function() {
    $('#dialog-contact-edit').dialog({
        modal: true,
        position: ["center", 100],
        width: 460,
        buttons: {
            "Close": function() {
                $(this).dialog("close"); },
            "Submit": function() {
                $(this).dialog("close"); }
        }
    });
});
```

Now the only issue is the last line of the ajax call:

```
$('#state-dropdown').empty().html(data);
```

I have a div in the form that should be emptied and filled with the data fetched with ajax.

If the div is placed on the main body of the page (outside the dialog) it works fine, but if it's inside the dialog, it is not updated.

Seems like there should be a simple fix for this, but I've spent hours searching and changing this and that ... all to no avail.

Any assistance from the brilliant minds here would be greatly appreciated.

Marie

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar problem with a form in a modal box (shadowbox to be specific). Question you need to answer: When the modal box opens, does it "clone" an piece of HTML already present inside the HTML (probably hidden) or does it load an iframe?

Shadowbox cloned the html content so I ended up having two elements with the same ID.

Problem was, only one id gets updated. So this is maybe the same problem you're having.

I had to either be specific to which one I wanted updating like $('#shadowbox . selector').

Or you could try to update the element by using a class instead of an id.
Like I said, if two elements have the same ID, only one will get called but if you use classes, they will all get updated.

Comment: Thanks.  I've been pretty good about making sure that I only have ONE of any ID on the page.

Comment: Well, I checked - and now the form is working.  I don't know what I did that fixed it ... I've been dinkering with the page, so maybe it was something wrong with the page - along the lines of what ComputerArts suggested.  Whatever, it's now working.